is it right to set visibility gone for adview? Admob
adview=findViewById(R.id.adView)
val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
adview.loadAd(adRequest)

I am using this code to load banner ads, but I also have a button that has to make it so it does not show the ads anymore and one solution I found is to write adView.visability=gone to its onclicklistener.
All I want to know if there will be any problems, will admob consider it as an impression if its disappeared anyway?

Update! it is better to use adView.destroy() when you don't want to show the ad, especially the banner one, and when you want to resume it just run the ad loading function.

Got the answer, the right thing to do is to write
adView.visability=gone and
adview.pause()
and if you want the banner to appear again you write adview.visibility=View.VISIBLE and
adview.resume()
